# Getting all permutations of a word where letters may have variants

Tags: algorithm, permutation

i am looking for the pseudocode algorithm to the following problem.

i want to get all permutations of a word. 
in the alphabet each letter may have variants. for example in french the letter e can also be é è ê ë.
the same with other letters... aàâä  etc.

now for any given word i want to list all the possible permutations with all variants of all letters.

input is a word and a all letters and their variants if they have some.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want that for, I can see you using it for generating a list of alternate searches. But if the word is long, that could conceivably contain a very large number of permutations.  Better to store a *normalised* version of the word, and normalise the search term to the base variant of the character.

Comment: well, i want that for the other way round. the user can type the word n the normalized version and i will need to check if a valid variant exists.

Comment: I would still do that via normalised versions.  Storing the variants against the normalised version wherever you store such things.  It would make it somewhat easier.  Hopefully whatever language you use will have some sort of transcoding library to auto-generate the normalised versions, *iconv* perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some basic pseudocode:

```
  1. Generate a list Perm[1...n] of all permutations without considering variants.
  2. For i = 1 to n do
  3.  For j = 1 to |Perm[i]| do
  4.   For k = 1 to #variants(Perm[i][j])
  5.    print Perm[i][1...j-1] (variant #k) Perm[i][j+1...|Perm[i]|]
```

In words, generate the permuations without considering variants (a problem already treated several times on SO, look for "generating permutations"). Then, for each permutation, look at each letter and for each of its permutations, print the word with the letter replaced by its variant.